# Summing repeated section calculated value

Tags: orbeon

I am trying to sum a calculated value inside a repeated section (`section-a-it`) and put the result on a calculated value outside the repeated section but it not working.

I have tried to declare the formula like of my sum field (`section-a-summary-total`) like

`sum($section-a-it/section-a-it-iteration/section-a-repetition/section-data/section-value-total[string() castable as xs:decimal])`

And all the combinations deleting one single section node each time.

My form looks like this:

```xml
<form>
    <section-a>
        <section-a-summary>
            <section-a-summary-total/>
        </section-a-summary>
        <section-a-it>
            <section-a-it-iteration>
                <section-a-repetition>
                    <section-data>
                        <section-percent/>
                        <section-value/>
                        <section-value-total/>
                    </section-data>                                    
                </section-a-repetition>
            </section-a-it-iteration>                            
        </section-a-it>                        
    </section-a>
</form>
```

Inside each iteration `section-value-total` is declared like `round-half-to-even($section-data-value* ($section-percent div 100))`

`section-value-total` works fine when I introduce values on `section-percent` and `section-value` but `section-a-summary-total` always is `0.00`

I've tryied this https://doc.orbeon.com/form-builder/formulas/formulas-examples#sum-of-values-in-a-repeat

I have attached initial source code in https://pastebin.com/eTHqY0ia

If I try to put this inside the sum() `round-half-to-even($section-value[string() castable as xs:decimal] * ($section-percent[string() castable as xs:decimal] div xs:decimal(100)),2)` sometimes works on first iteration

After trying some ideas and doing some changes in calculation, at this point with this version your solution works https://pastebin.com/6MSFq1WL I am capable of update value. I had to put `xxf:analysis.calculate="true"` because of values only were being calculated after a new row was added.

Comment: HCP, I haven't tried the code mentioned in my answer below, as I don't have the source of your form, so you'll let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to calculate your `section-a-summary-total` field as:

```
sum($section-value-total[string() castable as xs:decimal])
```

When you are outside of a repeated grid (outside of an "iteration"), and refer to the value of a field, the expression, in this case `$section-value-total`, returns the sequence of all the values for that field, which you can pass directly to `sum()`.

Comment: I have tried your solution but is still not working. I am wondering that the problem is someplace in rounding. I have tried to summing only section-value or section-percent and works but when I try to sum section-value-total does not work. Also i have tried to put the same formula inside the Sum arguments and sometimes works first iteration but when i add a second one, the summed value disappears.

Comment: I have attached new code with a funcional version after doing some calculation changes https://pastebin.com/6MSFq1WL I am pretty sure that it could be improved. Finally your solution worked! As allways thanks for all

Comment: Excellent @HCP, I'm glad you managed to make those calculations work, and thank you for the update. ‑Alex